# How to calculate a Clear Pixel's Green component value for a RCCB format picture?

Tags: image, computer-vision, rgb, sensors, colorfilter

Given the measured value of a Clear Pixel on a RCCB format picture's, and corresponding estimated value of  its Red\Blue component, how to calculate this Clear Pixel's Green component value?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Gvrj.png)

Comment: See the attached picture 1 in the link : [RCCB of Bayer Pattern CFA](https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-ce5bc0703d00a4e3a84d75d5eae9b493)

Comment: See the attached picture 1 in the link : [Light Spectrum of RCCB](https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-6ee78d922853ea71abbc2224e05d75eb)